# WKWebView App on ios 13 is showing a blank page

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I'm developing a ios app to embed my website inside a webview.
After setup the project and run the code, i'm getting a blank page on the ios simulator.
I already added the `NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent` and `NSAllowsLocalNetworking` to the `info.plist` file. When i inspect with the simulator with safari i only saw a `_aboutBlank`.

This is the code that i use to render the website into a webview.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate  {

    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.globo.com/")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

**Note:** if i change the url to **apple.com** it works.

Any ideas in how to solve this issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. I am seeing your website without a problem. Try to use delegate methods such as `webView(_:didFail:withError:)` to receive information about any errors that could happen when reaching the website.

Comment: I already added the didFail method, but is not catching nothing

Comment: What about `webView(_:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)` ? is it called?

Comment: No, i also implement the didFinish and didCommit but no one is called.

Comment: And its weird, because if i change my url to apple.com it works

Comment: Yes, actually I can load your website in my webView without any problems. Try `Erase All Contents and Settings` the simulator and try running the app again.

Comment: Unfortunately this not fix the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

After trying some options i found two ways to fix the problem.

1. Test on the real device
2. Create an app in ReacNative and use the Webview